# I need a to get a value in a map so that its key that includes a value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to do something like:

```
MyMap.set(['milk', 'eggs', 'flour'], 'ingredients');
MyMap.set(['red', 'green', 'blue'], 'colors');

console.log(MyMap.get(ELEMENT THAT INCLUDES eggs));
//expected: ingredients
```

I've tried a bunch of stuff, like using Array.has() and Array.includes(), but I just can't.
I'm new here and in coding, so sorry if i messed something up or if the solution is absurdly easy.

Comment: When you use an array (or any object) as a key, you can only retrieve the value using the exact same array. A different array that happens to have the same values will not work.

Comment: Beyond that, the Map API has no facility to do what you want. You'd have to get the Map entries and iterate through them yourself.

Comment: Are the items in all of the key arrays unique? The existing answer is sub-optimal but writing a better approach depends on this. A bit more information about your use case would be nice because this smells like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map Api doesn't support anything of this sort out of the box.
Here is one of the ways you can get it done.

```js
let MyMap = new Map();
MyMap.set(['milk', 'eggs', 'flour'], 'ingredients');
MyMap.set(['red', 'green', 'blue'], 'colors');
let valuesWhoseKeyIncludeText = [];
MyMap.forEach((value, key) => {
  if (key.includes('eggs')) {
    valuesWhoseKeyIncludeText.push(value);
  }
});
console.log(valuesWhoseKeyIncludeText);

//Above code returns Array of values whose key includes given text.
//So  if you have multiple entries in Map whose key includes given text then you will get array of values as result. e.g

let MyMap2 = new Map();
MyMap2.set(['milk', 'eggs', 'flour'], 'ingredients');
MyMap2.set(['red', 'green', 'blue'], 'colors');
MyMap2.set(['red', 'eggs', 'flour'], 'ingredientsAndColors');
let valuesWhoseKeyIncludeText2 = [];
MyMap2.forEach((value, key) => {
  if (key.includes('eggs')) {
    valuesWhoseKeyIncludeText2.push(value);
  }
});
console.log(valuesWhoseKeyIncludeText2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this seems difficult is that the structure doesn't support your use case. The key needs to be an exact match. Of course, you can dump the entire map contents and iterate over it every time you need to do a lookup with time complexity `O(size of map * longest array key)` which is pretty much throwing away the point of the data structure.

A better approach is to build the map by iterating over each element you'd normally associate with a value and performing multiple mappings to that value. This preserves the key-value semantics and supports `O(1)` lookup time.

In other words, instead of trying for (pseudocode):

```
{[key1, key2, key3]: val}
```

build this

```
{key1: val, key2: val, key3: val}
```

The downside of this approach is if you're setting values, you'd need to do it multiple times for each possible key mapping, but that doesn't appear to be your use case here.

Here's a minimal, complete example:

```js
const rawPairData = [
  [['milk', 'eggs', 'flour'], 'ingredients'], 
  [['red', 'green', 'blue'], 'colors'],
];

const map = new Map();

for (const [keys, val] of rawPairData) {
  for (const key of keys) {
    map.set(key, val);
  }
}

console.log(map.get('milk'));
console.log(Object.fromEntries([...map]));
```

Now, this assumes that keys are unique across all arrays. If you need to support a single key mapping to multiple values, follow the strategy as above but make the values arrays. Once again, setting is complex but lookups are fast after the one-off expense, so optimize for what I assume will be the common case.

```js
const rawPairData = [
  [['milk', 'eggs', 'flour'], 'ingredients'], 
  [['milk', 'eggs', 'blue'], 'colors'],
];

const map = new Map();

for (const [keys, val] of rawPairData) {
  for (const key of keys) {
    map.set(key, [...(map.get(key) ?? []), val]);
  }
}

console.log(map.get('eggs'));
console.log(Object.fromEntries([...map]));
```